# R dplyr replace "missing" column data with first non-"missing" value

Tags: r, dplyr, replace, missing-data, rowwise

This is a tricky one to describe concisely in a headline (or to google). I have a taxonomy table where some columns may be listed as "dropped' based on a confidence level. I'd like to replace any column that says "dropped" with "Unidentified" followed by the value from the first column that doesn't say "dropped", in a row-wise fashion. So, the input would look like this:

```r
#> # A tibble: 21 x 4
#>    domain    class       order           species
#>    <chr>     <chr>       <chr>           <chr>  
#>  1 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
#>  2 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
#>  3 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
#>  4 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
#>  5 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
#>  6 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
#>  7 Eukaryota Hexanauplia Calanoida       dropped
#>  8 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
#>  9 Eukaryota Dinophyceae Syndiniales     dropped
#> 10 Animals   Polychaeta  Terebellida     dropped
#> 11 Eukaryota Acantharia  Chaunacanthida  dropped
#> 12 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
#> 13 Animals   Ascidiacea  Stolidobranchia dropped
#> 14 Eukaryota Haptophyta  dropped         dropped
#> 15 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
#> 16 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
#> 17 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
#> 18 Animals   Ascidiacea  Stolidobranchia dropped
#> 19 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
#> 20 Eukaryota dropped     dropped         dropped
```

And the output should look like this:

```r
#> # A tibble: 21 x 4
#>    domain    class                order                species                  
#>    <chr>     <chr>                <chr>                <chr>                    
#>  1 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  2 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  3 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  4 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  5 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  6 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  7 Eukaryota Hexanauplia          Calanoida            Unidentified Calanoida   
#>  8 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  9 Eukaryota Dinophyceae          Syndiniales          Unidentified Syndiniales 
#> 10 Animals   Polychaeta           Terebellida          Unidentified Terebellida 
#> 11 Eukaryota Acantharia           Chaunacanthida       Unidentified Chaunacanth…
#> 12 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#> 13 Animals   Ascidiacea           Stolidobranchia      Unidentified Stolidobran…
#> 14 Eukaryota Haptophyta           Unidentified Haptop… Unidentified Haptophyta  
#> 15 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#> 16 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#> 17 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#> 18 Animals   Ascidiacea           Stolidobranchia      Unidentified Stolidobran…
#> 19 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#> 20 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota
```

I've come up with a fine solution using `purrr::pmap_dfr` but I'm curious to know if there's a more "pure" `dplyr` way to do it? The one flaw in my method is that it doesn't work for columns where the first non-"dropped" column comes after one or more "dropped" columns (see row 21 in the output below). Here's my current solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
otu_table <- structure(list(domain = c("Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", 
"Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", 
"Eukaryota", "Animals", "Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "Animals", 
"Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "Animals", 
"Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "dropped"), class = c("dropped", "dropped", 
"dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "Hexanauplia", "dropped", 
"Dinophyceae", "Polychaeta", "Acantharia", "dropped", "Ascidiacea", 
"Haptophyta", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "Ascidiacea", 
"dropped", "dropped", "not dropped"), order = c("dropped", "dropped", 
"dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "Calanoida", "dropped", 
"Syndiniales", "Terebellida", "Chaunacanthida", "dropped", "Stolidobranchia", 
"dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "Stolidobranchia", 
"dropped", "dropped", "dropped"), species = c("dropped", "dropped", 
"dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", 
"dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", 
"dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", "dropped", 
"dropped")), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

tax_data <- otu_table %>%
  pmap_dfr(~{
    items <- list(...)
    first_dropped = match("dropped",items)
    if (first_dropped > 1) {
      dropped_name <- str_c("Unidentified ",items[first_dropped-1])
    } else {
      dropped_name <- "Unidentified"
    }
    items[-c(1:first_dropped-1)] <- dropped_name
    items
  })
print(tax_data,n=30)
#> # A tibble: 21 x 4
#>    domain    class                order                species                  
#>    <chr>     <chr>                <chr>                <chr>                    
#>  1 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  2 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  3 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  4 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  5 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  6 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  7 Eukaryota Hexanauplia          Calanoida            Unidentified Calanoida   
#>  8 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#>  9 Eukaryota Dinophyceae          Syndiniales          Unidentified Syndiniales 
#> 10 Animals   Polychaeta           Terebellida          Unidentified Terebellida 
#> 11 Eukaryota Acantharia           Chaunacanthida       Unidentified Chaunacanth…
#> 12 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#> 13 Animals   Ascidiacea           Stolidobranchia      Unidentified Stolidobran…
#> 14 Eukaryota Haptophyta           Unidentified Haptop… Unidentified Haptophyta  
#> 15 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#> 16 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#> 17 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#> 18 Animals   Ascidiacea           Stolidobranchia      Unidentified Stolidobran…
#> 19 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#> 20 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukary… Unidentified Eukaryota   
#> 21 dropped   not dropped          dropped              dropped
```

**Update**:

Some good answers below. I've accepted the one with the most upvotes, but it turns out that after running all the suggestions through `microbenchmark`, the `purrr` solution is the fastest by almost an order of magnitude.

Comment: Make all your “dropped” true R NA and then use zoo::na.locf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach, using `rowwise()` in combination with `across()`.

- We are using `rowwise` because it helps in using a row as a single vector through `cur_data()`
- `across(everything(), ~)` helps us in mutating all columns at once
- `max.col(cur_data() != 'dropped', ties.method = 'last')` will retrieve last column index where the value `!= 'dropped'`
- we store its column name in a temp variable say `x`
- lastly we use `if()..else` from base R to mutate only those columns where value is `dropped`

Hope the answer is clear enough

```r
library(tidyverse)

otu_table %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ {x<- names(cur_data())[max.col(cur_data() != 'dropped', ties.method = 'last')]; 
  if (. == 'dropped') paste0('unidentified ', get(x)) else . }))

#> # A tibble: 21 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    domain    class                 order                 species                
#>    <chr>     <chr>                 <chr>                 <chr>                  
#>  1 Eukaryota unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryota 
#>  2 Eukaryota unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryota 
#>  3 Eukaryota unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryota 
#>  4 Eukaryota unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryota 
#>  5 Eukaryota unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryota 
#>  6 Eukaryota unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryota 
#>  7 Eukaryota Hexanauplia           Calanoida             unidentified Calanoida 
#>  8 Eukaryota unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryo~ unidentified Eukaryota 
#>  9 Eukaryota Dinophyceae           Syndiniales           unidentified Syndinial~
#> 10 Animals   Polychaeta            Terebellida           unidentified Terebelli~
#> # ... with 11 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I think execution time for this is quite decent, however, you may try it for yourself. I would like to thank @IRTFM for his comment with regard to changing `dropped` values to `NA`. I actually used that idea but I decided to err on the side of `dplyr` than `zoo` so instead of `na.locf` I used `coalesce` for this purpose.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

otu_table %>%
  mutate(across(!domain, ~ replace(.x, .x == "dropped", NA))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(output = list(coalesce(c_across(everything()), 
                                str_c("Unidentified", 
                                      last(c_across(everything())[!is.na(c_across(everything()))]), sep = " ")))) %>%
  select(output) %>%
  unnest_wider(output) %>%
  set_names(colnames(otu_table))


# A tibble: 21 x 4
   domain    class                  order                  species                 
   <chr>     <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>                   
 1 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota  
 2 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota  
 3 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota  
 4 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota  
 5 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota  
 6 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota  
 7 Eukaryota Hexanauplia            Calanoida              Unidentified Calanoida  
 8 Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota Unidentified Eukaryota  
 9 Eukaryota Dinophyceae            Syndiniales            Unidentified Syndiniales
10 Animals   Polychaeta             Terebellida            Unidentified Terebellida
# ... with 11 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using dplyr + tidyr::pivot_longer/wider. I think it reads cleanly but there's surely a more concise way.

```
otu_table %>%
  mutate(across(class:species, ~if_else(.x == "dropped", NA_character_, .x))) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(is.na(value) & !is.na(lag(value)), paste("Unidentified", lag(value)), value)) %>%
  fill(value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

Comment: That's nice! Although according to microbenchmark, it's a bit over 30 times slower than the `pmap` method. But, I had forgotten about both the fill and lag functions and those will come very much in handy!